# Python socket error in command prompt but not in idle

Tags: python, sockets

This is the standard code for a simple socket program given in my class at Coursera.

The main problem is this code runs perfectly in IDLE but fails when run through cmd prompt in Windows 10. I have attacjed screen shots that show the problem.

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
        break
    print (data);

mysock.close()
```

[image]

The screen shot shows the error in cmd but not in IDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your script named `socket`, so in your script:

```
import socket
```

will import itself. Python will search modules in current directory before search `PATH`.  Rename it...For example, `socket_program.py`, will resolve this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yea I remember my instructor saying you cannot write the same name as your functions...